# Properly shutting down send-only NServiceBus Endpoint in a WCF Application

Tags: c#, wcf, nservicebus

We are trying to host a send-only endpoint within a WCF service. Due to its fire-and-forget nature, the WCF hosting option [here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/wcf/) isn't really what we are looking for, since we don't want to wait for the messagehandler to have to reply. In other words, all our WCf methods are void/Task.

However, we are having trouble figuring out how to deal with properly shutting down the endpoint. WCF doesn't really have a lifecycle API to use to handle shutdown behaviour.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Do send-only endpoints *need* to be shutdown?
2. If so, how would I do this in a WCF service?

Comment: You can choose to shut down the endpoint, when the process shuts down, the endpoint should stop. ‘endpointInstance?.Stop().GetAwaiter().GetResult();’https://docs.particular.net/samples/endpoint-configuration/#shut-down-the-endpoint and https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/lifecycle/endpointstartandstop

Comment: @LanHuang I know that API exists. I'm asking when to call it. In WCF, is there an event or something I can subscribe to? Is there any hook that tells me when the application is shutting down?

Comment: You don't 'need' to shutdown a send-only endpoint. It is more critical for processing endpoints to shutdown gracefully, as there may be messages in-flight being processed.

Comment: @HadiEskandari I was guessing as much, but I could never find it explicitly in the documentation. Feel free to make this a full answer :)

Comment: Posted as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't 'need' to shut down a send-only endpoint. It is more critical for processing endpoints to shutdown gracefully, as there may be messages in-flight being processed.